# Trigger an email from a video being watched

Tags: php, email, video, notifications

I was wondering if it is possible to burn a video presentation to a CD, and then when I send it to the prospective client it will trigger an email (maybe by pinging a server that triggers php code?) that would send back to me to notify that the video was watched.

I have no idea how this would be done... or if it is possible.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It is possible, but unethical, if not possibly even illegal in many jurisdictions.

Comment: don't send them the video, send them a link, then you can see they opened the link

Comment: The problem is that I would like to send something physical - since an email is too easy to just delete.  A package is much more intriguing....I'm not trying to be unethical at all....just know when they have watched the presentation.

Comment: Advertise the heck out of your site on the DVD, with a special url like `dvd.example.com` so they'll only know to visit it if they've seen the DVD.

Comment: @Scott: Throwing a cd into the trash is about as easy as deleting an email.

Comment: I would think any one who wanted to send me physical media, has been asleep for about a decade.

Answer (score 1):

I think using a background notification is a privacy violation. User should be informed of the notification. 
An alternative would be to put some restricted material on a website. The link would be provided at the end of the presentation.